# receiving webpages using windows sockets(C ++),but got some unexpected words

Tags: c++, sockets, http

I am trying to get a webpage with sockets,using http GET.I do get the page,but there is something little wrong.
Sometimes I got it all right,but sometimes I got it with wrong characters like:

```
        **<td class="c_ba2636">09</t
```

1ff8
d>**

it should be :

```
        <td class="c_ba2636">09</td>
```

I donot know why there is a "1ff8" and some "\r\n".
It happens here and there from time to time.And sometimes it occurs like:
            06

again it should be :

```
   <td class="c_ba2636">06</td>
```

this is how I receive and save the page from a socket:

```
                     ofstream out("webpage.html");
         char text[2050]="";

         int recvbytes=0;
         string content;
         while ( (recvbytes = recv(sock, text, 2048, 0)) > 0)
         {
             content=string(text,recvbytes);
             out << content.c_str();
             //System::Console::Write(gcnew String(content.c_str()));
         }

         closesocket(sock);
         out.close();
```

I tried :out << text; it did not work.
Please does anyone know what's wrong with my codes.
I am using VS2010,and this is a winform program.

Comment: Please, fix the code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

It may be normal if your input text is UTF8 encoded and contains characters out of ASCII space

Comment: I am not sure,It seems it happens randomly,and I do not think it is out of ASCII space,they are just chars

Answer (score 0):

Now I got it done.it turns out that those "1ff8" "2000" or whatever are from some http protocols,to indicates something(length?).I just need to delete those lines and rearrange the lines that are interrupted by them.So I add a function:

```
private: void rearrangment()
    {
        ifstream ifile("webpage.html");
        ofstream ofile("web.html");
        char line1[2048]="";
        char line2[2048]="";
        char line3[2048]="";
        ifile.getline(line1,2047);
        //ifile.getline(line2,2047);
        while(!ifile.eof())
        {
            ifile.getline(line2,2047);

            if(string(line2,0,3)!="   " 
                && line2[0]!='<' && line2[1]!='<' && line2[2]!='<')//they are "1ff8"s
            {
                ifile.getline(line3,2047);
                for(int i=0;i<2046;++i)
                {
                    if(line1[i]==13)
                    {
                        line1[i]=0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                strcat(line1,line3);

            }
            else
            {
                ofile<<line1<<endl;
                strcpy(line1,line2);
                //ofile<<line1;
            }
            //ofile<<line1;
        }
        ifile.close();
        ofile.close();
    }
```

and now it works well.
Sorry about this stupid question,I should have searched before I  asked.